# How do I delete a versioned bucket in AWS S3 using the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli, s3cmd

I have tried both `s3cmd`:

```
$ s3cmd -r -f -v del s3://my-versioned-bucket/
```

And the AWS CLI:

```
$ aws s3 rm s3://my-versioned-bucket/ --recursive
```

But both of these commands simply add `DELETE` markers to S3. The command for removing a bucket also doesn't work (from the AWS CLI):

```
$ aws s3 rb s3://my-versioned-bucket/ --force
Cleaning up. Please wait...
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
remove_bucket failed: s3://my-versioned-bucket/ A client error (BucketNotEmpty) occurred when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.
```

Ok... how? There's no information in [their documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html) for this. S3Cmd says it's a 'fully-featured' S3 command-line tool, but it makes [no reference to versions](http://s3tools.org/usage) other than its own. Is there any way to do this without using the web interface, which will take forever and requires me to keep my laptop on?

Comment: As far as i know, you would need to iterate through the object versions and delete them in batches of 1000...

Comment: If there's sample Java code for this somewhere, that would be great. AWS documentation is really terrible...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do it is iterate through the versions and delete them. A bit tricky on the CLI, but as you mentioned Java, that would be more straightforward:

```
AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
String bucketName = "deleteversions-"+UUID.randomUUID();

//Creates Bucket
s3.createBucket(bucketName);

//Enable Versioning
BucketVersioningConfiguration configuration = new BucketVersioningConfiguration(ENABLED);
s3.setBucketVersioningConfiguration(new SetBucketVersioningConfigurationRequest(bucketName, configuration ));

//Puts versions
s3.putObject(bucketName, "some-key",new ByteArrayInputStream("some-bytes".getBytes()), null);
s3.putObject(bucketName, "some-key",new ByteArrayInputStream("other-bytes".getBytes()), null);

//Removes all versions
for ( S3VersionSummary version : S3Versions.inBucket(s3, bucketName) ) {
    String key = version.getKey();
    String versionId = version.getVersionId();          
    s3.deleteVersion(bucketName, key, versionId);
}

//Removes the bucket
s3.deleteBucket(bucketName);
System.out.println("Done!");
```

You can also batch delete calls for efficiency if needed.

Comment: I was actually going to try getting a multithreaded program running to delete each of the 'folders' in my S3 bucket (there are four of them), and if needed split the threads for the larger folders into `first/1`, ..., `first/9`, etc. ... but a coworker and I just ended up deleting all the versions using the web interface and Cyberduck. Thanks for the help when I needed it though!

Comment: The important stuff to remember when writing a bulk-delete script

* you may have to use a region-specific endpoint for deleting versions (check bucket location)

* you have to delete all Versions and DeleteMarkers

Answer (score 163):

I ran into the same limitation of the AWS CLI. I found the easiest solution to be to use Python and [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.object_versions):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

BUCKET = 'your-bucket-here'

import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)
bucket.object_versions.delete()

# if you want to delete the now-empty bucket as well, uncomment this line:
#bucket.delete()
```

A previous version of this answer used [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto3) but that solution had performance issues with large numbers of keys as Chuckles pointed out.

Comment: best solution!!

Comment: This worked great for me too!  Only snag was installing boto successfully on Arch linux, for which this worked a treat: `pip3 install boto3 --user <username>`

Comment: I'm not a Python developer and I primarily prefer Node.js instead of Python, but this package looks like a best solution so far.

Comment: Worked great. Just wanted to add that the bucket needs to be specified without any prefix. Otherwise, it threw validation error. This worked: `BUCKET = 'my-bucket-name'`

Comment: For anyone needing to use profiles for multi-role and/or multi-account usage, adding `boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='YOUR_PROFILE_NAME')` before creating the s3 resource is necessary...

Comment: One note here - it appears that `object_versions` is not an iterator, so it must accumulate the entire list in memory. I watched this 4 line python script consume 7GB of virt memory before it actually started deleting anything. Kudo's for the post though, it did work. I'm just whining about the fact that boto's method is not an iterator when one could clearly benefit here.

Comment: Could you consider making this Python3 and argv style as I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70650812/7412781 ? If so I can remove my answer far below.

Comment: For some reason this is not deleting my object versions.

Comment: worked for me, before using bot3 do pip3 install bot3, I did it in console itself, It worked very fast. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend running this in a CloudShell in the same region your bucket is located.  The script doesn't provide any feedback but it emptied a 40GiB bucket with millions of versions in about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 60):

Using `boto3` it's even easier than with the proposed `boto` solution to delete all object versions in an S3 bucket:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('your-bucket-name')
bucket.object_versions.all().delete()
```

Works fine also for very large amounts of object versions, although it might take some time in that case.

Comment: what if I want to keep the current versions but delete everything else?

Answer (score 53):

You can delete all the objects in the versioned s3 bucket.
But I don't know how to delete specific objects.

```
$ aws s3api delete-objects \
      --bucket <value> \
      --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions \
      --bucket <value> | \
      jq '{Objects: [.Versions[] | {Key:.Key, VersionId : .VersionId}], Quiet: false}')"
```

Alternatively without `jq`:

```
$ aws s3api delete-objects \
    --bucket ${bucket_name} \
    --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions \
    --bucket "${bucket_name}" \
    --output=json \
    --query='{Objects: Versions[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"
```

Comment: Any way of getting around the 1000+ objects limitation?

Comment: Nice one, but as mentioned in other answers Versions might not be enough and you might need to delete DeleteMarkers too.

Comment: Correct, DeleteMarkers need to be deleted as well. (having just tried this)

Comment: @BruceEdge could you update the answer to reflect deletion of deletemarkers aswell? Thank you

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K I addressed this later by creating a policy that deleted versions more than 1 day old. Now, when I want to delete a versioned bucket, I apply the policy, then disable versioning. Then the policy takes care of all the old versions. (There wasn't an easy way to delete the markers in a single command)

Comment: @BruceEdge doesn't answer 2 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61123579/629287 take care of deleting markers in a single command?

Comment: @chris, yes, it appears to.I don't remember if I tried that or not. Looks worth a try.

Comment: I used `((.Versions // []) + (.DeleteMarkers // []))[]` instead of simply `.Versions[]` to take care of DeleteMarkers in a one-liner using `jq`.

Answer (score 43):

This two bash lines are enough for me to enable the bucket deletion !

1: Delete objects
`aws s3api delete-objects --bucket ${buckettoempty} --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ${buckettoempty} --query='{Objects: Versions[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"`

2: Delete markers
`aws s3api delete-objects --bucket ${buckettoempty} --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ${buckettoempty} --query='{Objects: DeleteMarkers[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"`

**EDIT:** If you have 500+ items in your S3 bucket and you get `Argument list too long` error, you will need to loop on the above command to empty your bucket :

```sh
NB_OBJECTS=$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ${buckettoempty} --query='length(Versions[*] || `[]` )' | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo "      '${NB_OBJECTS}' objects to remove"
if [[ "$NB_OBJECTS" != "0" ]]; then
  start=$SECONDS
  while [[ $NB_OBJECTS -gt 0 ]]
  do
    aws s3api delete-objects --bucket ${buckettoempty} --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ${buckettoempty} --max-items 500 --query='{Objects: Versions[0:500].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')" --query 'length(Deleted[*] || `[]` )' > /dev/null
    NB_OBJECTS=$((NB_OBJECTS  > 500 ? NB_OBJECTS - 500 : 0))
    echo "      Removed batch of Objects... Remaining : $NB_OBJECTS ($(( SECONDS - start ))s)"
  done
fi

NB_OBJECTS=$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ${buckettoempty} --query='length(DeleteMarkers[*] || `[]` )' | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo "      '${NB_OBJECTS}' markers to remove"
if [[ "$NB_OBJECTS" != "0" ]]; then
  start=$SECONDS
  while [[ $NB_OBJECTS -gt 0 ]]
  do
    aws s3api delete-objects --bucket ${buckettoempty} --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ${buckettoempty} --max-items 500 --query='{Objects: DeleteMarkers[0:500].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')" --query 'length(Deleted[*] || `[]` )' > /dev/null
    NB_OBJECTS=$((NB_OBJECTS  > 500 ? NB_OBJECTS - 500 : 0))
    echo "      Removed batch of Markers... Remaining : $NB_OBJECTS (took $(( SECONDS - start ))s)"
  done
fi
```

Comment: Doing this on the command line can yield a `Argument list too long` exception. If you run into this, leverage the `--max-items` argument on the `list-object-versions` call (I did batches of 500).

Comment: or you can use `DeleteMarkers[0:999]`

Answer (score 28):

Looks like as of now, there is an `Empty` button in the AWS S3 console.
[image: Empty Button]

Just select your bucket and click on it.  It will ask you to confirm your decision by typing `permanently delete`
Note, this will not delete the bucket itself.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work on expired buckets. Please test this on a small bucket before doing this. Otherwise you will spend hours on this without realizing the problem.

Answer (score 19):

If you have to delete/empty large S3 buckets, it becomes quite inefficient (and expensive) to delete every single object and version. It's often more convenient to let AWS expire all objects and versions.

```sh
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration \
  --lifecycle-configuration '{"Rules":[{
      "ID":"empty-bucket",
      "Status":"Enabled",
      "Prefix":"",
      "Expiration":{"Days":1},
      "NoncurrentVersionExpiration":{"NoncurrentDays":1}
    }]}' \
  --bucket YOUR-BUCKET
```

Then you just have to **wait 1 day** and the bucket can be deleted with:

```sh
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket YOUR-BUCKET
```

Comment: it is a smart idea :D

Answer (score 15):

Here is a one liner you can just cut and paste into the command line to delete all versions and delete markers (it requires aws tools, replace yourbucket-name-backup with your bucket name)

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > deleteBucketScript.sh \
&& aws --output text s3api list-object-versions --bucket $BUCKET_TO_PERGE \
| grep -E "^VERSIONS" |\
awk '{print "aws s3api delete-object --bucket $BUCKET_TO_PERGE --key "$4" --version-id "$8";"}' >> \
deleteBucketScript.sh && . deleteBucketScript.sh; rm -f deleteBucketScript.sh; echo '#!/bin/bash' > \
deleteBucketScript.sh && aws --output text s3api list-object-versions --bucket $BUCKET_TO_PERGE \
| grep -E "^DELETEMARKERS" | grep -v "null" \
| awk '{print "aws s3api delete-object --bucket $BUCKET_TO_PERGE --key "$3" --version-id "$5";"}' >> \
deleteBucketScript.sh && . deleteBucketScript.sh; rm -f deleteBucketScript.sh;
```

then you could use:

`aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force`

Comment: My co-worker set up life cycle rules that will slowly delete the versioning buckets over the next several days. Your answer is ironic in that it spells the end of S3 versioning in our system forever.

Comment: From what I can see, this is the only actual CLI-based answer that caters for buckets of any size that actually works.

Comment: Upvoting for the correctness of the answer but this code is really hard to read and understand.

Comment: Building a script, executing it, and then deleting the script is pretty cool, but you can pass the arguments directly to bash with xargs and execute them immediately with multiple threads.

`aws --output text s3api list-object-versions --bucket MY_BUCKET
| grep -E "^VERSIONS" | xargs -P8 -l bash -c 'aws s3api delete-object --bucket MY_BUCKET --key "$3" --version-id "$7"'`

Note that the indexes are shifted by 1 because bash uses zero indexing.

Answer (score 12):

For those using multiple profiles via `~/.aws/config`

```
import boto3

PROFILE = "my_profile"
BUCKET = "my_bucket"

session = boto3.Session(profile_name = PROFILE)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)
bucket.object_versions.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for your pythonic answer.  Works for millions of objects (though you have to leave it open for a long time).  And since python is interactive, it feels like a CLI answer ;)

Comment: You can pass profile as an option using cli as well -
`aws s3api delete-objects --profile <my_profile> --bucket <my_bucket> --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket <my_bucket> | jq -M '{Objects: [.["Versions","DeleteMarkers"][]|select(.Key == "key-value")| {Key:.Key, VersionId : .VersionId}], Quiet: false}')"`

Comment: can I specify prefix level as well?

Comment: @VishalGori  Is there a way to print what is being deleted similar to what aws s3 rm would ? I'm running this pyscript but don't know whether the program is running or stuck.

Answer (score 10):

If you want pure CLI approach (with jq):

```
aws s3api list-object-versions \
          --bucket $bucket \
          --region $region \
          --query "Versions[].Key"  \
          --output json | jq 'unique' | jq -r '.[]' | while read key; do
   echo "deleting versions of $key"
   aws s3api list-object-versions \
          --bucket $bucket \
          --region $region \
          --prefix $key \
          --query "Versions[].VersionId"  \
          --output json | jq 'unique' | jq -r '.[]' | while read version; do
     echo "deleting $version"
     aws s3api delete-object \
          --bucket $bucket \
          --key $key \
          --version-id $version \
          --region $region
   done
done
```

Comment: how to filter only those Having Delete Mark and delete those ?

Answer (score 10):

Simple bash loop I've found and implemented for N buckets:

```
for b in $(ListOfBuckets); do \
    echo "Emptying $b"; \
    aws s3api delete-objects --bucket $b --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $b --output=json --query='{Objects: *[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"; \
done
```

Comment: I think this might only work for buckets with fewer than 1000 objects, and will not delete the deletion markers. Also, the OP did not ask about multiple buckets; as you can see from the other answers, complete deletion of contents of versioned bucket is the tricky part, not deleting multiple buckets.

Answer (score 7):

1. For deleting specify object(s), using jq filter.
2. You may need cleanup the 'DeleteMarkers' not just 'Versions'.
3. Using `$()` instead of ``` `` ```, you may embed variables for bucket-name and key-value.

```
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket bucket-name --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket bucket-name | jq -M '{Objects: [.["Versions","DeleteMarkers"][]|select(.Key == "key-value")| {Key:.Key, VersionId : .VersionId}], Quiet: false}')"
```

Comment: This oneliner (as well as the one above http://stackoverflow.com/a/31086407/465684 ) look and work nice, but they do not cater for the situation when there are more than 1000 objects to delete (hard limitation of the s3api delete-objects call).

Comment: @tiger-peng Got the error "An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the DeleteObjects operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema". Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @MarcellodeSales, if you can share what command you used, I may try to check it out.

Comment: I'm using the solution below with Python... I gave up on the aws cli

Answer (score 7):

I ran into issues with [Abe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306665/4269215) as the `list_buckets` generator is used to create a massive list called `all_keys` and I spent an hour without it ever completing. This tweak seems to work better for me, I had close to a million objects in my bucket and counting!

```
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket("your-bucket-name-here")

chunk_counter = 0 #this is simply a nice to have
keys = []
for key in bucket.list_versions():
    keys.append(key)
    if len(keys) > 1000:
        bucket.delete_keys(keys)
        chunk_counter += 1
        keys = []
        print("Another 1000 done.... {n} chunks so far".format(n=chunk_counter))

#bucket.delete() #as per usual uncomment if you're sure!
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else encountering this S3 nightmare!

Comment: Thank you for the example this helped me out, one thing this is missing a final bucket.delete_keys(keys) after the for loop to catch any stragglers based on your batching logic here.

Answer (score 7):

Even though technically it's not AWS CLI, I'd recommend using AWS Tools for Powershell for this task. Then you can use the simple command as below:

```
Remove-S3Bucket -BucketName {bucket-name} -DeleteBucketContent -Force -Region {region}
```

As stated in the documentation, DeleteBucketContent flag does the following:

> "If set, all remaining objects and/or object versions in the bucket
> are deleted proir (sic) to the bucket itself being deleted"

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Remove-S3Bucket.html

Comment: This solution actually worked far better than the others.  Namely, because we have Powershell tools which work on cross-platform Powershell now, this was the fastest solution to get my bucket deleted without much effort.  This will receive my bounty once I can award it later tonight.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you for the bounty. I appreciate it.

Comment: Well, your answer was the only one that not only included the mechanism to delete the bucket but a straightforward integrated-into-the-command way to purge all content and versions as well.  None of the other solutions worked  - even the aws s3api calls didn't work they hardexploded on "Must delete all versions" and emptying the bucket didn't help, so this was the only solution that really worked for me here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from the AWS Console using Lifecycle Rules.

Open the bucket in question. Click the Management tab at the top. 
Make sure the Lifecycle Sub Tab is selected. 
Click + Add lifecycle rule

On Step 1 (Name and scope)  enter a rule name (e.g. removeall)
Click Next to Step 2 (Transitions) 
Leave this as is and click Next.

You are now on the 3.  Expiration step. 
Check the checkboxes for both Current Version and Previous Versions.
Click the checkbox for "Expire current version of object" and enter the number 1  for "After _____ days from object creation
Click the checkbox for "Permanently delete previous versions"  and enter the number 1 for 
"After _____  days from becoming a previous version"

click the checkbox for "Clean up incomplete multipart uploads"
 and enter the number 1 for "After  ____  days from start of upload"
Click Next
Review what you just did.
Click Save

Come back in a day and see how it is doing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I improved [the boto3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306665/7412781) with Python3 and argv.

1. Save the following script as something like `s3_rm.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import boto3

def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if (len(args) < 1):
        print("Usage: {} s3_bucket_name".format(sys.argv[0]))
        exit()

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(args[0])
    bucket.object_versions.delete()

    # if you want to delete the now-empty bucket as well, uncomment this line:
    #bucket.delete()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

2. Add `chmod +x s3_rm.py`.
3. Run the function like `./s3_rm.py my_bucket_name`.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as https://stackoverflow.com/a/63613510/805031 ... this is what I use to clean up accounts before closing them:

```
# If the data is too large, apply LCP to remove all objects within a day

# Create lifecycle-expire.json with the LCP required to purge all objects
# Based on instructions from: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-empty-bucket-lifecycle-rule/
cat << JSON > lifecycle-expire.json
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ID": "remove-all-objects-asap",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": ""
            },
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 1
            },
            "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
                "NoncurrentDays": 1
            },
            "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
                "DaysAfterInitiation": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "ID": "remove-expired-delete-markers",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": ""
            },
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "Expiration": {
                "ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
JSON

# Apply to ALL buckets
aws s3 ls | cut -d" " -f 3 | xargs -I{} aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket {} --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle-expire.json

# Apply to a single bucket; replace $BUCKET_NAME
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle-expire.json
```

...then a day later you can come back and delete the buckets using something like:

```
# To force empty/delete all buckets
aws s3 ls | cut -d" " -f 3 | xargs -I{} aws s3 rb s3://{} --force

# To remove only empty buckets
aws s3 ls | cut -d" " -f 3 | xargs -I{} aws s3 rb s3://{}

# To force empty/delete a single bucket; replace $BUCKET_NAME
aws s3 rb s3://$BUCKET_NAME --force
```

It saves a lot of time and money so worth doing when you have many TBs to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I found the other answers either incomplete or requiring external dependencies to be installed (like boto), so here is one that is inspired by those but goes a little deeper.

As documented in [Working with Delete Markers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeleteMarker.html), before a versioned bucket can be removed, all its versions must be completely deleted, which is a 2-step process:

1. "delete" all version objects in the bucket, which marks them as
   deleted but does not actually delete them
2. complete the deletion by deleting all the deletion marker objects

Here is the pure CLI solution that worked for me (inspired by the other answers):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bucket_name=...

del_s3_bucket_obj()
{
    local bucket_name=$1
    local obj_type=$2
    local query="{Objects: $obj_type[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}"
    local s3_objects=$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ${bucket_name} --output=json --query="$query")
    if ! (echo $s3_objects | grep -q '"Objects": null'); then
        aws s3api delete-objects --bucket "${bucket_name}" --delete "$s3_objects"
    fi
}

del_s3_bucket_obj ${bucket_name} 'Versions'
del_s3_bucket_obj ${bucket_name} 'DeleteMarkers'
```

Once this is done, the following will work:

```
aws s3 rb "s3://${bucket_name}"
```

Not sure how it will fare with 1000+ objects though, if anyone can report that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest method I've found is to use this CLI tool, `s3wipe`. It's provided as a docker container so you can use it like so:

```
$ docker run -it --rm slmingol/s3wipe --help
usage: s3wipe [-h] --path PATH [--id ID] [--key KEY] [--dryrun] [--quiet]
              [--batchsize BATCHSIZE] [--maxqueue MAXQUEUE]
              [--maxthreads MAXTHREADS] [--delbucket] [--region REGION]

Recursively delete all keys in an S3 path

optional arguments:
  -h, --help               show this help message and exit
  --path PATH              S3 path to delete (e.g. s3://bucket/path)
  --id ID                  Your AWS access key ID
  --key KEY                Your AWS secret access key
  --dryrun                 Don't delete. Print what we would have deleted
  --quiet                  Suprress all non-error output
  --batchsize BATCHSIZE    # of keys to batch delete (default 100)
  --maxqueue MAXQUEUE      Max size of deletion queue (default 10k)
  --maxthreads MAXTHREADS  Max number of threads (default 100)
  --delbucket              If S3 path is a bucket path, delete the bucket also
  --region REGION          Region of target S3 bucket. Default vaue `us-
                           east-1`
```

#### Example

Here's an example where I'm deleting all the versioned objects in a bucket and then deleting the bucket:

```
$ docker run -it --rm slmingol/s3wipe \
   --id $(aws configure get default.aws_access_key_id) \
   --key $(aws configure get default.aws_secret_access_key) \
   --path s3://bw-tf-backends-aws-example-logs \
   --delbucket
[2019-02-20@03:39:16] INFO: Deleting from bucket: bw-tf-backends-aws-example-logs, path: None
[2019-02-20@03:39:16] INFO: Getting subdirs to feed to list threads
[2019-02-20@03:39:18] INFO: Done deleting keys
[2019-02-20@03:39:18] INFO: Bucket is empty.  Attempting to remove bucket
```

#### How it works

There's a bit to unpack here but the above is doing the following:

- `docker run -it --rm mikelorant/s3wipe` - runs `s3wipe` container interactively and deletes it after each execution
- `--id` & `--key` - passing our access key and access id in
- `aws configure get default.aws_access_key_id` - retrieves our key id
- `aws configure get default.aws_secret_access_key` - retrieves our key secret
- `--path s3://bw-tf-backends-aws-example-logs` - bucket that we want to delete
- `--delbucket` - deletes bucket once emptied

#### References

- https://github.com/slmingol/s3wipe
- [Is there a way to export an AWS CLI Profile to Environment Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852223/is-there-a-way-to-export-an-aws-cli-profile-to-environment-variables)
- https://cloud.docker.com/u/slmingol/repository/docker/slmingol/s3wipe

Comment: The idea looked promising, but I'm getting the following error: `ERROR: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request` for some reason. Also, the `aws configure get default.aws_access_key_id` is not working so I have to manually pass the credentials.

Comment: Better use `--env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --env AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as args to docker run, so the key info is not available in shell commands history, but I have not checked if s3wipe uses them (it should).

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/wknapik/191619bfa650b8572115cd07197f3baf

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eEo pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit >/dev/null 2>&1 || true

if [[ ! "$#" -eq 2 || "$1" != --bucket ]]; then
    echo -e "USAGE: $(basename "$0") --bucket <bucket>"
    exit 2
fi

# $@ := bucket_name
empty_bucket() {
    local -r bucket="${1:?}"
    for object_type in Versions DeleteMarkers; do
        local opt=() next_token=""
        while [[ "$next_token" != null ]]; do
            page="$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket "$bucket" --output json --max-items 1000 "${opt[@]}" \
                        --query="[{Objects: ${object_type}[].{Key:Key, VersionId:VersionId}}, NextToken]")"
            objects="$(jq -r '.[0]' <<<"$page")"
            next_token="$(jq -r '.[1]' <<<"$page")"
            case "$(jq -r .Objects <<<"$objects")" in
                '[]'|null) break;;
                *) opt=(--starting-token "$next_token")
                   aws s3api delete-objects --bucket "$bucket" --delete "$objects";;
            esac
        done
    done
}

empty_bucket "${2#s3://}"
```

E.g. `empty_bucket.sh --bucket foo`

This will delete all object versions and delete markers in a bucket in batches of 1000. Afterwards, the bucket can be deleted with `aws s3 rb s3://foo`.

Requires bash, awscli and jq.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Maybe running later versions of something and above > 1000 items. been running a couple of million files now. However its still not finished after half a day and no means to validate in AWS GUI =/

```python
# Set bucket name to clearout
BUCKET = 'bucket-to-clear'

import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)

max_len         = 1000      # max 1000 items at one req
chunk_counter   = 0         # just to keep track
keys            = []        # collect to delete

# clear files
def clearout():
    global bucket
    global chunk_counter
    global keys
    result = bucket.delete_objects(Delete=dict(Objects=keys))

    if result["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] != 200:
        print("Issue with response")
        print(result)

    chunk_counter += 1
    keys = []
    print(". {n} chunks so far".format(n=chunk_counter))
    return

# start
for key in bucket.object_versions.all():
    item = {'Key': key.object_key, 'VersionId': key.id}
    keys.append(item)
    if len(keys) >= max_len:
        clearout()

# make sure last files are cleared as well
if len(keys) > 0:
    clearout()

print("")
print("Done, {n} items deleted".format(n=chunk_counter*max_len))
#bucket.delete() #as per usual uncomment if you're sure!
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to python solutions provided here: if you are getting   `boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request` error, try creating ~/.boto file with the following data:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key
[s3]
host=s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key
```

Helped me to delete bucket in Frankfurt region.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41200567/2586441

Answer (score 0):

If you use AWS SDK for JavaScript S3 Client for Node.js (@aws-sdk/client-s3), you can use following code:

```
const { S3Client, ListObjectsCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')


const endpoint = 'YOUR_END_POINT'
const region = 'YOUR_REGION'

// Create an Amazon S3 service client object.
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region, endpoint })

const deleteEverythingInBucket = async bucketName => {
  console.log('Deleting all object in the bucket')

  const bucketParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName
  }

  try {
    const command = new ListObjectsCommand(bucketParams)
    const data = await s3Client.send(command)
    console.log('Bucket Data', JSON.stringify(data))
    if (data?.Contents?.length > 0) {
      console.log('Removing objects in the bucket', data.Contents.length)
      for (const object of data.Contents) {
        console.log('Removing object', object)
        if (object.Key) {
          try {
            await deleteFromS3({
              Bucket: bucketName,
              Key: object.Key
            })
          } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error on object delete', err)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error creating presigned URL', err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I wanted to be sure that all objects for specific prefixes would be deleted. So, we generate a list of all objects for each prefix, divide it by 1k records (AWS limitation), and delete them.

Please note that `AWS CLI` and `jq` must be installed and configured.

A text file with prefixes that we want to delete was created (in the example below `prefixes.txt`).

The format is:

```
prefix1
prefix2
```

And this is a shell script (also please change the `BUCKET_NAME` with the real name):

```
#!/bin/sh

BUCKET="BUCKET_NAME"
PREFIXES_FILE="prefixes.txt"

if [ -f "$PREFIXES_FILE" ]; then
    while read -r current_prefix
    do
        printf '***** PREFIX %s *****\n' "$current_prefix"

        OLD_OBJECTS_FILE="$current_prefix-all.json"

        if [ -f "$OLD_OBJECTS_FILE" ]; then
            printf 'Deleted %s...\n' "$OLD_OBJECTS_FILE"

            rm "$OLD_OBJECTS_FILE"
        fi

        cmd="aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket \"$BUCKET\" --prefix \"$current_prefix/\" --query \"[Versions,DeleteMarkers][].{Key: Key, VersionId: VersionId}\"  >> $OLD_OBJECTS_FILE"
        echo "$cmd"
        eval "$cmd"

        no_of_obj=$(cat "$OLD_OBJECTS_FILE" | jq 'length')
        i=0
        page=0

        #Get old version Objects
        echo "Objects versions count: $no_of_obj"

        while [ $i -lt "$no_of_obj" ]
        do
            next=$((i+999))
            old_versions=$(cat "$OLD_OBJECTS_FILE" | jq '.[] | {Key,VersionId}' | jq -s '.' | jq .[$i:$next])
            paged_file_name="$current_prefix-page-$page.json"
            cat << EOF > "$paged_file_name"
{"Objects":$old_versions, "Quiet":true}
EOF
            echo "Deleting records from $i - $next"
            cmd="aws s3api delete-objects --bucket \"$BUCKET\" --delete file://$paged_file_name"
            echo "$cmd"
            eval "$cmd"

            i=$((i+1000))
            page=$((page+1))
        done

    done < "$PREFIXES_FILE"
else
    echo "$PREFIXES_FILE does not exist."
fi
```

If you want just to check the list of objects and don't delete them immediately - please comment/remove the last `eval "$cmd"`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete older object versions but keep the current version in the bucket. Code uses iterators, works on buckets of any size with any number of objects.

```py
import boto3
from itertools import islice

bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('bucket_name'))
all_versions = bucket.object_versions.all()
stale_versions = iter(filter(lambda x: not x.is_latest, all_versions))
pages = iter(lambda: tuple(islice(stale_versions, 1000)), ())
for page in pages:
    bucket.delete_objects(
        Delete={
            'Objects': [{
                'Key': item.key,
                'VersionId': item.version_id
            } for item in page]
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script will help you delete huge data in S3 bucket with object versioning enabled and delete markers

```
#!/bin/bash

export AWS_PROFILE=ABC

bucket_name="XYZ"
max_items_per_page=1000  # Adjust this as needed

set -e

echo "Removing all versions from $bucket_name"

next_token=""

while true; do
    result=$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket "$bucket_name" --max-items $max_items_per_page --starting-token "$next_token")
    versions=$(echo "$result" | jq '.Versions')
    markers=$(echo "$result" | jq '.DeleteMarkers')

    if [ "$versions" == "null" ] && [ "$markers" == "null" ]; then
        echo "No more versions to delete."
        break
    fi

    # Removing files
    for version in $(echo "$versions" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
        version=$(echo "$version" | base64 --decode)

        key=$(echo "$version" | jq -r .Key)
        versionId=$(echo "$version" | jq -r .VersionId)
        cmd="aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucket_name --key $key --version-id $versionId"
        echo "$cmd"
        $cmd
    done

    # Removing delete markers
    for marker in $(echo "$markers" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
        marker=$(echo "$marker" | base64 --decode)

        key=$(echo "$marker" | jq -r .Key)
        versionId=$(echo "$marker" | jq -r .VersionId)
        cmd="aws s3api delete-object --bucket $bucket_name --key $key --version-id $versionId"
        echo "$cmd"
        $cmd
    done

    next_token=$(echo "$result" | jq -r '.NextToken')
done
```

Answer (score -1):

If you got [rclone](https://rclone.org/) installed, you can use [rclone purge](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_purge/) command to delete versioned bucket.

Follow the [configuration guide](https://rclone.org/s3/#configuration) and setup s3 remote, following snippet uses `s3` as the name when configuring the remote.

```bash
rclone purge --verbose s3:my-versioned-bucket
```

Comment: Answer looks like it's taken from chatgpt

Comment: This requires a recent version of rclone and use of the `--s3-versions` flag

Answer (score -2):

You can use **aws-cli** to delete **s3 bucket**

> aws s3 rb s3://your-bucket-name

If **aws cli** is not installed in your computer you can your following commands:
For Linux or ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install aws-cli

Then check it is installed or not by:

> aws --version

Now configure it by providing aws-access-credentials

> aws configure

Then give the access key and secret access key and your region