# aws cloudformation snippet for S3 Bucket to apply LifecycleConfiguration to delete all existing versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, versioning, bucket

The lifecycle configuration yaml template snippet must delete all existing previous versions as well as current versions from now on. The versioning is suspended for this bucket. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I dont think cloudformation can do that.

Comment: @ArunK any ideas or suggestions to try to achieve that?

Comment: Adding to @ArunK point, Lifecycle configuration mgmt policy does not delete all versions. It just puts a delete marker to the latest version and all other versions still exists in the bucket.

Comment: @ChandanKumar what would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: You have to use AWS SDK or CLI, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @ChandanKumar OMG thats going to be a lot of files.

Comment: cant you simply create a life cycle policy to delete all previous versions in 1 day? you could do this directly on s3 console

Comment: @PainPoints no, no you don't need to go through all the files and delete one by one. It just a API call, checkout my answer. Though it may take some time if you have more files but this behaviour is expected even if you use any other method(other SDK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Boto3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('your-bucket-name')
bucket.object_versions.all().delete()
```

You can do it on [GUI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/view-object-versions.html) too but that would take lots of time if you have lots of files.

You can find further possible ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809105/how-do-i-delete-a-versioned-bucket-in-aws-s3-using-the-cli).