# Cannot able to delete all the objects in the versioned S3 bucket using CLI and while executing terraform destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, command-line-interface

Got this error while deleting the versioned S3 bucket in AWS:

```
aws s3 rb s3://rapport1-0-ap1-dev-01 --force
```

> remove_bucket failed: s3://rapport1-0-ap1-dev-01 An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.

Did the following execution of command:

1.Empty the S3 Bucket

`aws s3 rm s3://rapport1-0-ap1-dev-01 --recursive`

2.Disable the versioning of the bucket

`aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --apport1-0-ap1-dev-01--versioning-configuration Status=Suspended`

3.Force delete the bucket

`aws s3 rb s3://apport1-0-ap1-dev-01 --force`

Got the below error while executing the `aws s3 rb s3://apport1-0-ap1-dev-01 --force`

> remove_bucket failed: s3://rapport1-0-ap1-dev-01 An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.

It works when I delete the versioned objects in the console and deleted the bucket.

Comment: Terraform definitely won't be able to delete the bucket for you. Regarding the CLI commands you are trying, this seems like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809105/how-do-i-delete-a-versioned-bucket-in-aws-s3-using-the-cli